# Default phone lock screen layout

Tags: java, android, layout, lockscreen

I'm creating a game for android and I need to create a layout which looks exactly the same as default phone lock keyboard. Is there anyway to get this module from the phone? I don't want to style it on my own cause the layout would be different then the default one.